# Where should I process query results when using CursorLoader?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

Where should I process query results (time consuming task) when using CursorLoader?

Comment: In an extra thread? what's the problem?

Comment: I'm looking for best solution. Should I start asynctask in onLoadFinished?

Comment: An AsyncTask is a good solution if the task only takes a few seconds max. You can then use the proposed solution of Udi Oshi. If the task takes longer (minutes), you should not use asyntask, but create a Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTask to load data from cursor and return values in onPostExcute method (uiThread), when you'll call the task multiple times cancel the the former.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateLoader then once the result is processed, return null or cursorloader to notify that you are done doing background task and update your ui in onLoadFinished